# Just printing the kasra or tanwin in ArabTex

Tags: arabic, arabtex

I read the documentation but I can't find a way to print that kind of result :
[image]

When I write:

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\begin{document}

\setarab
\vocalize
\arabtrue

\RL{uN}
\RL{aN}
\RL{iN}

\end{document}
```

it gives an alif with the tanwin. I would like at least to erase the alif. Having the same thing as the picture above would be the best.

Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. Could you add a [minimum working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) to your post?

Comment: I added what I have for the moment.@AlainRemillard

Comment: How about  `xelatex` or `lualatex`? `arabtex` is somewhat old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tanwin damma is character 024 (see `arabsymb.sty` in the installation directory of ArabTeX). You can print that as a single character after switching to the Arabic font, see `arabtex.sty` for some examples.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\begin{document}
\setarab
\vocalize
\arabtrue

\RL{uN}
\makeatletter \bgroup \set@arabfont \char'024 \egroup \makeatother

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Combined with the `stackengine` package to recreate the example, using a circle from `wasysym`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\begin{document}
\setarab
\vocalize
\arabtrue

\makeatletter \bgroup \set@arabfont
\stackunder{\Circle}{\char'023}
\stackon{\Circle}{\char'024}
\stackon{\Circle}{\char'023}\par
% or a bit closer
\stackunder[1pt]{\Circle}{\char'023}
\stackon[1pt]{\Circle}{\char'024}
\stackon[1pt]{\Circle}{\char'023}
\egroup \makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! That's almost it but it will only work for `\RL{uN}`. Because `\RL{aN}` and `\RL{iN}` are using the same `\char'` . The placement of the symbol is how we differentiate both. So I need to remove the alif but still keep the white space.

Comment: `aN` and `iN` are the same the difference is just the position on or below the letter, you can move up to obtain an `aN`  or down to obtain an `iN` like this 
`\raisebox{2ex}{\char'023}` and `\raisebox{-.5ex}{\char'023}`.

Comment: @AyBenDh see the edit for an example of character placement using `stackengine`.

Comment: That's perfect ! Thank you so much !